# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm working in test automation project with the combination of JAVA,MAVEN and TESTNG. Test cases working fine in local environment but JENKINS build encountered following error. Not sure what is missing between environments.

I have changed some configs in POM as guided over internet. Nothing works

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default- 
  test) on project Getter_Web_UI: There are test failures/ 
     [ERROR] Please refer to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testING/target/surefire-reports for the 
    individual test results.
        [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and 
         [date].dumpstream.
       [ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
         [ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
   [ERROR]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:733)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:305)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:265)
    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1314)
```

**POM.XML**

```
enter code here<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.TESTING</groupId>
<artifactId>TESTING</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>3</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
           </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Read the error log from Surefire properly.

Comment: @tibor17 This works for me now, forget to update the answer

Comment: Why you have <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader> and <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>? It is not recommended.

Comment: @tibor17 i have tried whatever option provided over internet

Comment: I am a developer of Surefire in the Apache. You should understand the settings. Many people don;t and then the problems start. Was there any problem why you used these settings?

Answer (score 1):

These Steps helped me to resolve

1. updated to from jdk16 Java jdk 8 or 11 to support jenkins Build run.
2. Plugin management tags aligned properly.

   ```
     <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>                                                   
                        <include>Sample.java</include>
                    </includes>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>



        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
   ```

now surefire able to pick the test and run.

Comment: The problem is that you did not obey the standards. Why your test class is "Sample.java"? It should be "SampleTest" located in src/test/java/<package>.

Comment: @tibor17  sample.java is actual test class i have renamed it. from <include></include> test cases picked and run for test executions

Comment: What if my tests use java 11 language features? I would guess it breaks beacuse the configurations sets it to java 1.8